# Textarea форматирование

Tags: html, php, mysql

Вопрос в следующем. Когда сохраняешь из textarea текст в Mysql, он сохраняется в отформатированном виде (без тегов). Например вот так:

```
    Параграф. Начало текста.

  Текст после пропуска строки.
```

В таком виде он помещается в таблицу и каким-то образом хранит это форматирование (пропуск строки, пробелы и т.д.). Если выводить его просто в html - все новые строки и пробелы потеряются (если при этом не использовать nl2br (он дает возможность сохранить пропуск строк, но не количество пробелов)). Если выводить из Mysql обратно в textarea этот текст - все норм показываются пропуски строк и пробелы). Вопрос: как добиться тогоже при выводене в textarea, а просто в html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 вариант

> <pre>Текст</pre>

2 вариант, заменить пробелы на &nbsp; и \n на <br > при выводе в html